# sorting order on a field ( mediaOrder ) which belongs to a pivot ( Middle ) table does not work

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to apply sorting order on a field ( mediaOrder ) which belongs to a pivot ( Middle ) table and pivot does not have any entity because we are using ORM with below mentioned Relation.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=MediaItem::class, cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="template_facebook_post_media_item",
 *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="template_facebook_post_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="media_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 * @Groups({"template-read"})
 */
private $mediaItems;
```

I tried to apply order by but did not work as expected.
using above code i got facebookposts with mediaItems but mediaItems are not sorted by Newly added mediaOrder column in pivot table.

i split because doctrine did not allow order by in pivot table so i made a new entity and update the relation  below my three file code

and newly created entity code is here

```
 <?php
    namespace App\Entity;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
     /**
     * @ORM\Entity()
     * @ORM\Table(name="template_facebook_post_media_item")
     */
     class TemplateFacebookPostMediaItem
  {
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=TemplateFacebookPost::class, inversedBy="templateFacebookPostMediaItems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="template_facebook_post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $templateFacebookPost;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=MediaItem::class, inversedBy="templateFacebookPostMediaItems")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="media_item_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $mediaItem;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $mediaOrder;
public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTemplateFacebookPost(): ?TemplateFacebookPost
{
    return $this->templateFacebookPost;
}

public function setTemplateFacebookPost(?TemplateFacebookPost $templateFacebookPost): self
{
    $this->templateFacebookPost = $templateFacebookPost;

    return $this;
}
public function getMediaItem(): ?MediaItem
{
    return $this->mediaItem;
}
public function setMediaItem(?MediaItem $mediaItem): self
{
    $this->mediaItem = $mediaItem;
    return $this;
}
public function getMediaOrder(): ?int
{
    return $this->mediaOrder;
}

public function setMediaOrder(int $mediaOrder): self
{
    $this->mediaOrder = $mediaOrder;

    return $this;
   }
 }
```

and FacebookPost entity is

```
 <?php
namespace App\Entity;
  use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
 use App\Repository\TemplateFacebookPostRepository;
  use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\JoinColumn;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
* @ApiResource(
*     itemOperations={"get"},
 *     collectionOperations={}
* )
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=TemplateFacebookPostRepository::class)
 */
class TemplateFacebookPost
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Groups({"template-read"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"template-read"})
 */
private $message;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"template-read"})
 */
private $linkUrl;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"template-read"})
 */
private $name;

/**
 * 
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=TemplateFacebookPostMediaItem::class,mappedBy="templateFacebookPost", orphanRemoval=true, cascade= 
{"persist"})
    */
   private $templateFacebookPostMediaItems;
```

now i am getting result only Facebook post but that should be with multiple media item array  with it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Without these class definition nobody can help us. so please let it be for proceed